# Using Firebase Database with large data some queries

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to Firebase Jason Seq.database system I going to develop a web module and a android app with firebase as back-end wanna some suggestion on some points before I start:

- 1: Currently having a Database with largest table with approx 2
  million records is it possible to migrate :any tools suggestion or
  methodology?
- 2: any methodology to arrange data in Fire base to handle large
  data.?
- 3: Data is large but  my user count are limited in a geo region (max
  10000/day) so dose it fit in my budget?

Comment: Just sharing my experienced, Firebase is not providing multiple queries on single request. Means if you have user data, you want to fire query like i want user having age > 18 & who are living in India, then it is bit difficult in Firebase.

Comment: No, it's not. It's quite simple. If you'll get familiar with the main concepts, you'll be able to do everything you want.

Comment: Chintan Their must  be way  to that  its a minor feature in any database system afterall firebase is hosting many big app in IOS and Andriod community

Comment: @ChintanRathod You can upload JSON data directly to firebase and 2m rows is easily done. Also, performing queries in Firebase is quite powerful and by leveraging concatenated fields can be easily done. For example a node may have three children; location: India, age: 18, loc_age: india_18. The query would be to query on loc_age.startingAt("india_18"). That will return all users in India who are over 18.

Comment: @Jay Yes. I came to know about this. But the point is i require to create an extra column for combination of cells on which i want to perform action. As in your example, loc_age is an extra burden to our database. Now suppose what would be query string for person searching, nationality -> india, age > 18 & gender = male?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible to migrate to Firebase even if your database is very large. To archieve this, i suggest you watch this tutorial, [The Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WacqhiI-g_o&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s&index=1). Even if Firebase is a NoSQL Database, i'm sure you'll be very familiar in short time.
2. Yes, the key for doing this is to have the data as flatten as possible. Please take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data). Will be very helpful.
3. If you'll be able to have a Firebase database as much as possible, as it described in the tutorial above, you'll be able to have less to pay. For pricing, take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)!.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex it helps me