# Reading Data from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app where a user can create an event and see other events created by other users only if there are in a 10Km Radius. I am storing all the data in firestore.

This is how the app works, from the user side all the events are fetched and only those events are displayed whose distance is less than 10km.

The problem is if there are **10,000** events in the database and the user is in the **10km** radius of only **10** events then obviously it will count as **10,000** reads which is too expensive.

*Any suggestions for this problem? 
One solution that I have in mind is to store data according to the geographical area but how to implement it is another problem.*

Answer (score 0):

You won't be charge for 10 000 reads but only the documents retrieved by your query, ten in your example.

Here's a good video from Firebase explaining their billing system : https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=224&v=6NegFl9p_sE

Also keep in mind that for queries other than document reads, such as a request for a list of collection IDs, you are billed for one document read.

Comment: Of course I made hypothesis that you know event and user location, I though it was obvious

Comment: What I mean is that my code will fetch 10,000 events first and then it will check the location of the event, after that it will compare the user's location with the event location. if the distance is less than 10km then only it will display.

Comment: it's more like this fetch one event, compare it and then display it like this for all the 10,000 events. That is why it will count as 10,000 reads

Answer (score 0):

I suggest computing min and max longitude corresponding to 10 km distance from user longitude. You do the same with latitude and use those limits in Firestore query. Doing so You will have less events/reads and you can compute the exact distance to suppress events between 10 and 14 km radius... if necessary.

To compute your limit you can use the following formula from https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html (Destination point given distance and bearing from start point) and there's an online javascript calculator you can study.

φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )

λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance traveled in meters, R the earth’s radius (6371e3).

With bearing 0° you obtain LatitudeMax

With bearing 90° you obtain longitudeEast

With bearing 180° you obtain LatitudeMin

With bearing 270° you obtain longitudewest

Since earth is a sphere with longitude between -180° and 180°

longitudeMin = Min(longitudeEast, longitudeWest)

longitudeMax = Max(longitudeEast, longitudeWest)

And The Firestore part is like :

```
CollectionReference col = Firestore.instance.collection("mycollection");

Query latitudeMinQuery = col.where('latitude', isGreaterThan: LatitudeMin);
Query latitudeMaxQuery = latitudeMinQuery.where('latitude', isLessThan: LatitudeMin);
Query longitudeMinQuery = latitudeMaxQuery.where('longitude', isGreaterThan: LongitudeMin);
Query longitudeMaxQuery = longitudeMinQuery.where('latitude', isLessThan: LongitudeMax);
```

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: Nope, it didn't :(

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804487/9139407 (answers by @alex-mamo)

Hopes it helps!

Comment: Don't think this answer the OP question